# Can't install GooglePlayServices.Base package for Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play-services, nuget-package

So I have a `cross-platform` project (`IOS and Android`) and I need to install `GooglePlayServices.Base` `NuGet`package for my `Android` project, but I get this error when trying that:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyApp.Android'.

I know it's an error of non-compatibility of versions, but I can't figure out where exactly.

Here are the versions of all components of the project:

- Xamarin.Forms `2.5.1.317207-pre1`.
- Project property > Application > compile using android version : `Android 8.0 (Oreo)`.
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base `v60.1142.0` (need to be installed).

Some people were saying that only GooglePlayServices.Base `32.940.0-beta3` works for Xamarin.Forms, but this one also didn't work for me.

Any Idea?!

UPDATE:

I could install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base `v42.1021.1` but I need to use `GcmClient` in my code and this one again needs `v60.1142.0`.

Comment: Any news? Same Problem here.

Comment: Hi @ArneNöhre , Not really, still using v42.1021.1 and couldn't implement push notification because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, in case anyone else ever has this issue, If you take a look at the nuget package manager console output, you can actually see the solution right there. In my case the error message was:

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement. Install/reference Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1 directly to project LoyaltyWorx.Android to resolve this issue. 
 LoyaltyWorx.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 60.1142.1) 
 LoyaltyWorx.Android -> LoyaltyWorx -> Plugin.PushNotification 1.3.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 60.1142.0).
```

I therefore proceeded to install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1